# How to share hierachical data over multiple instances of views in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am building a project browser, which looks a bit like a simple file explorer. In order to make the project management easier, I would like it should be able to open more than one instance of views, so the user can copy/paste from one view to the other without much scrolling in one view. The "Project Browser" mainly consists of a tree-control, which represents the structure of the project. There can be more than one project, but only one project is shown in the tree-view. I am not using any framework (only Telerik Controls, but they don't affect the Problem) but I am aware of the MVVM Pattern.

The data shown in the view is gathered from a Request Layer which does the DB Stuff. Since it is also possible, that the shown projects can have many items in a node/folder, data is loaded on demand. Whole data is not present after initializing.

Now my problem is, if I bind all project browser views to the same View-Model, they began behave like "twins". If I select one item in one view, it will be selected in the other views too. That's not what I need. I need to share the data across all views, but not the visual state of the data.

I think, I could handle it if I create one View-Model instance for every view instance. But then I have to wire up many events, because all data for every View-Model have to be synchronous. Each item and Child-Collection in the Tree/View-Model have to be connected to its counterparts in the other instances. I am wondering if there is a simpler/other solution for my problem (or if I am misguided at any other point).

Comment: How about a shared "Model" Instance on two seperate ViewModels?